# jQuery image slide show carousel when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I've been trying to build an image slide show / carousel using jQuery, and came across [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) which I thing is really good, and does things the way I want to.

I'm stuck with how to build a slide show of images when using the ajax method they have.

I have six images per item that i'd like to load from the server, and run as a slideshow / carousel just like you see them when you click on the first link on this [page](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/) under Elastic Transition.

I've succeeded in getting the images to the script using ajax, but i don't end up with a slide show. How can I do this? I currently end up with all the images below each other, and no forward or backward buttons etc.

Can you help?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a class='ajax' href="../content/ajax.html">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.html (pulls images and returns it to the script**

```
<div>
    <img class="gallery" src='/slide/content/ohoopee1.jpg'>
    <img class="gallery" src='/slide/content/ohoopee2.jpg'>
    <img class="gallery" src='/slide/content/ohoopee3.jpg'>
</div>
```

I just could not figure what to do more.

[image]

**Desired**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using ajax to add the markup to your document, then assign and open Colorbox to those elements.

An example would be something like this:

```
<div id='pictures' style='display:none'></div>
<script>
    $('.ajax').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(this.href, {
            success: function(html) {
                $('#pictures').html(html).find('img').colorbox({href: function(){
                    return this.src;
                }, open:true});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I made a few adjustments here and there and got it going. Will show you the finished version in some time.